# Why can't I relocate these specific messages from chat?

Tags: bug, chat, moderator-tools

I'm trying to relocate these specific chat messages ( https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4227661#4227661 to https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4228994#4228994 ) from [The Assembly](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2691/the-assembly) to the [Recycle Bin](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/364/recycle-bin)

However, after selecting the room, nothing seems to happen. The error console doesn't show any errors either. What's failing here?

Comment: Hmmm? I just moved it...

Comment: @yoda you moved Mrozek's posts, not the entire thing.. uh, the links to transcript shows no message. hmm.